# do I understand continuous time white noise correctly?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I've been reading about continuous time white noise. **I want to test if I understand it correctly.**

Suppose we have white noise $\zeta(\cdot): \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$. Then any particular "manifestation" of $\zeta$, will result in a function, let's call it $f(t)$. Since for any two $t_1, t_2$, $\zeta (t_1)$ is probabilistically independent from $\zeta (t_2)$.

$f(t)$ is really a bizarre function it seems to me. **Here are some intuitive conjectures** that seem to me must hold for any $f(t)$ *almost-surely*:

1. **$f(t)$ will be discontinuous for every $t\in \mathbb R$.**
2. **No matter how close you get to a particular $t$, the values next to it never touch, or come close to $f(t)$.** $f(0)$ could be for example $2.3563...$, while if $dt$ is an infinitessimally small number (forget about rigorously defining that for a moment), then $f(0+dt)$ could for example be $-0.534534...$
3. If we take two random points $t_1, t_2$, then **the range of $f(t)$ on the domain $(t_1,t_2)$ will be $(-\infty,\infty)$**, because there are an uncountable amount of real numbers between $t_1, t_2$, and white noise has the normal distribution, so that given an infinite amount of "draws" from that white noise, every number will eventually be drawn.

**Bonus:**
$f(t)$ cannot be differentiated obviously, but we can (in some way) define an integral $\int_0^xf(t)dt$. This integral will equal $0$ for all $x$ *almost-surely*. This should be possible, because while $f$ is discontinuous, there are an infinite amount of "draws" from the normal distribution, so that according to the law of large numbers, the average distance between $f(t)$ and the $t-axis$ is $0$ with probability $1$.

**Are my conjectures correct?**